# Access SQL Query: group by month, also if not present

Tags: sql, ms-access

in my table `Table2` I have some amounts organized by date. Not all the months are present.

I need a query that gives me one row for each month of a year, so 12 rows: January, February, and so on.

For each month; I need the sum of all the amounts of the same month and the result by month.

I have tried with the following code that gives me `Table2 Query` but it is not what I need. For example, here we have just 6 months instead of 12 and they are not organized chronologically.

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Format$([Table2].[Data],'mmmm yyyy') AS [Data By Month], Sum(Table2.Budget) AS [Sum Of Budget]
FROM Table2
GROUP BY Format$([Table2].[Data],'mmmm yyyy'), Year([Table2].[Data])*12+DatePart('m',[Table2].[Data])-1;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using Access. Sorry but I don't know which SQL it is.

Comment: . . In MS Access, you would need a calendar table for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can either have a year-month table/query and create an outer join to your table, or you can create a Cartesian query generating the year-month range on the fly:

```
SELECT 
    Format(DateSerial(Year([Data]),[Month],1),"mmmm yyyy") AS YearMonth, 
    Sum(Nz(IIf(DateSerial(Year([Data]),[Month],1)=DateSerial(Year([Data]),Month([Date]),1),Table2.[Budget],0),0)) AS Total
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Tens]+[Ones] AS [Month], 
        10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) AS Tens, 
        Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) AS Ones
    FROM 
        MSysObjects AS Uno, 
        MSysObjects AS Deca) AS Months, 
    Table2
WHERE
    Months.[Month] Between 1 And 12
GROUP BY 
    DateSerial(Year([Data]),[Month],1)
ORDER BY 
    DateSerial(Year([Data]),[Month],1);
```

The subquery (*Months*) generates numbers between 0 and 100. These are filtered to month values of 1 to 12.

Then the budget values are summed, grouped by year-month.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a variable with a table with all the months and then join it with your table and your sum has to be ISNULL(SUM(...), 0)

You can create that table this way ...

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME, @ToDate DATETIME;
SET @FromDate = '2018-01-01';
SET @ToDate = '2018-12-31';
DECLARE @Dates table (
  TheDate date,
  month integer,
  year integer);

INSERT into @Dates 
SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @FromDate, @ToDate)+1) 
 TheDate  = DATEADD(MONTH, number, @FromDate),
 TheMonth = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, number, @FromDate)),
 TheYear  = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, number, @FromDate))
FROM [master].dbo.spt_values 
WHERE [type] = N'P' ORDER BY number;

Select * FROM @Dates
```